# How to write mocha/chai test case for jQuery/JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mocha.js, chai

I am new to Mocha/ Chai test case writing. I am not sure how to write test case for the below jQuery+JS function. Can somebody help me on this.

```
    define(function (require) {
    'use strict';


    return function controllerFunction(context) {

     this.onReady = function(){
           $('#consentProgressStep').focus();

          var btn = $('#buttonElement')[0];

          if(btn){ 
               btn.addEventListener('click-next', nextClick);

               btn.addEventListener('click-cancel', function() {
                    this.trigger('cancelClick');
          });
      };

 });

 });
```

Comment: What's `this`? Can you show the context?

Comment: this.onReady and this.trigger are the method we have in controller file. 'this' is controller context.

Comment: Please give a minimal, complete code.

Comment: @slideshowp2 updated my post with code.